Ubuntu LTS 24.04 Python pywbem Module Installation/Compatibility
I have recently built a new Ubuntu 24 LTS 24.04 with GUI Desktop and it runs Nagios Core. I am struggling with getting the check_esxi_hardware.py script working.
It worked on an old Ubuntu 16 LTS VM. I have done the following:

Gotten the latest (I believe) version of the check from GitHub

Installed python using the following commands:
 sudo apt-get install python3-pip
 sudo apt-get install sblim-wbemcli

(apt-get install python-pywbem is depreciated)


Initially I got the below when I'd try doing a ./check_esxi_hardware.py:
-bash: ./check_esxi_hardware.py: cannot execute: required file not found

If I run the following:
sudo apt install python-is-python3

I will then be able to get the following:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/nagios/libexec/./check_esxi_hardware.py", line 300, in <module>
    import pywbem
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pywbem'

Is there a way to download and install the pywbem module into 24.04 LTS to get this esxi check to work or is it simply not compatible?

@Archisman I see you're mass-adding tags now. Please understand that just because something is used in the answer doesn't mean the question is about it. The tabs define what the question is about. This question doesn't involve pip, even if your answer does. Similarly, another question in which you added the flatpak tag because your answer is about flatpak doesn't mean the question is about it.

The official website says that the package was removed from the Ubuntu repository in 20.04, but you can install it with pip instead.
sudo apt install python3-pip
sudo pip3 install pywbem --break-system-packages

Note that it will not break any system packages as pywbem is not available as a system package anyway.

This worked from a manual check standpoint. Get the following in the nagios check.
(No output on stdout) stderr: Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_esxi_hardware.py", line 300, in 
import pywbem
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pywbem'

Can you try sudo pip3 install pywbem --break-system-packages

That worked. Any repercussions I should be worried about? It did throw this after the install was done: WARNING: Running pip as the 'root' user can result in broken permissions and conflicting behaviour with the system package manager. It is recommended to use a virtual environment instead: https://pip.pypa.io/warnings/venv

Since pywbem is not available on the official repositories, there should not be any issue. The issue would only arise if one tries to install pywbem from APT, but that is unavailable.

In principle you can install pywbem in a virtual environment and run ./check_esxi_hardware.py from within that, but it is really not necessary.

"Since pywbem is not available on the official repositories, there should not be any issue. " Often the problem with sudo pip install foo breaking stuff is not foo itself, but the dependencies. You might well end up installing some version of a dependency which conflicts with some system-installed version, and that's what typically breaks the system.

Thanks for all the help and info, greatly appreciated!

You can accept my answer by clicking the checkmark on the left side, if it solved your problem
